# $cordovaFileTransfer is not working when upload file to s3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ionic-framework, aws-sdk

I have tried to **upload mp4 file to aws s3 bucket** using   `$cordovaFileTransfer` plugin.

This is mycode

```
 bucket.getSignedUrl('putObject', {
              Key: 'uploads/ghdfdgjfjhs.mp4'
            }, function(err, url) {
              console.log('The URL is', url);
              document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {

                $cordovaFileTransfer.upload(url,  $scope.clip, {})
                  .then(function(result) {
                    console.log(result);
                  }, function(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                  }, function(progress) {

                  });

              }, false);

            });
```

Signed url is return successfully. 
But return following error

```
ssl=0xaf974000: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: What is the hostname in the generated URL?

Comment: this is ionic app . server host is aws-s3 bucket url

Comment: Right... but I am asking what the hostname of the generated URL looks like... for example, `my-bucket-name.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com`.

Comment: https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/buckets-test/uploads/0102f2ef-6c6…Dddhguhdguhdugh&Expires=1480398832&Signature=a7NLP8nBcexK3loxdhLnPaZ6uzE%3D

Comment: this is my bucket sign url

Comment: If `buckets-test` is really your bucket name, you should find that this bucket is actually in the `ap-northeast-1` region, not `eu-west-1`, so this URL is incorrect.

Comment: those are correct. i have uploaded file different way but uploded file is base64 encoded. Then i have use this way

Comment: @ding7890 It seems to me that we have the same issue. Check my question and answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40843853/ionic-android-upload-file-to-s3-using-presigned-url-error-code-3/40863601#40863601